# es6: what is the value of result using spread operator?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

came across this code learning redux and react.

my question is what the final result looks like when the spread oeprator is used. if I understand it correctly it basically turns iterable or array into individual arguments.

so I expect that the output is just creating another JSON object using all the fields obtained via the ... operator.

```
const INITIAL_STATE = { postsList: {posts: [], error:null, loading: false},  
                        newPost:{post:null, error: null, loading: false}, 
                        activePost:{post:null, error:null, loading: false}, 
                        deletedPost: {post: null, error:null, loading: false},
                    };

export default function(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
  let error;
  switch(action.type) {

  case FETCH_POSTS:// start fetching posts and set loading = true
    return { ...state, postsList: {posts:[], error: null, loading: true} };
```

so is this the result of FETCH_POSTS:

```
{ 
postsList: {posts: [], error:null, loading: false},  
                            newPost:{post:null, error: null, loading: false}, 
                            activePost:{post:null, error:null, loading: false}, 
                            deletedPost: {post: null, error:null, loading: false, },
```

so basically it was smart enough to know that there existed the `postsList` key and overwritten it?

now is it anti-pattern to rely on checking the existence of the state for the react.js app? meaning "if this key exists do this" instead of "if key value is null do this"

why don't you just change the value of the key via array key? INITIAL_STATE['postsList'] = {...postsObject}

or is using the spread operator the new pattern?

Comment: The result of FETCH_POSTS would be `{ 
postsList: {posts: [], error:null, loading: true},  
                            newPost:{post:null, error: null, loading: false}, 
                            activePost:{post:null, error:null, loading: false}, 
                            deletedPost: {post: null, error:null, loading: false, },` since that's being set in the return. `...` essentially replaces Object.assign() https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Comment: As @rrostt mentioned Redux state *must* be considered immutable. There's some good documentation about how to do that here: http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/ImmutableUpdatePatterns.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Object.assign and ... spread operator is good for shallow copying. For deep copying, I prefer lodash/deepClone or deepCopy util like this.

```
export default function deepCopy(obj) {
  if (typeof obj === 'object' && Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === '[object Array]') {
    let finalObj = [];
    for (let i = 0, len = obj.length; i < len; ++i) {
      finalObj.push(deepCopy(obj[i]));
    }
    return finalObj
  } else if (typeof obj === 'object') {
    let finalObj = {};
    for (let prop in obj) {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        finalObj[prop] = deepCopy(obj[prop]);
      }
    }
    return finalObj;
  } else {
    return obj;
  }
}
```

I blindly deep-copy my state to a new state. And then apply Object.assign to various objects. So, my code will be:

```
const newState = deepCopy(state);
Object.assign(newState.prop1, { innerProp: 'val' });
```

Comment: This is a *terrible* way to do things. Deep copying prevents any form of mutations on the old state, sure, but it doesn't re-use any of the state that has not changed. This is bad for at least 3 reasons. 1) It uses more memory 2) It takes time to copy everything and 3) React-Redux knows if something has not changed by triple-equals comparing. When deep-cloning, everything has changed according to React-Redux and the whole app will be rerendered on each tiny change. A performance nightmare.

Comment: @DDS, Thanks for your comment. If I mutate arrays in my old state, it causes bugs. So, is the solution to do a shallow copy, create new arrays, and leave other nested objects which are not mutated?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the solution. just `.slice()` the array. Also, replace any objects that change with new ones (no mutations). But do not replace objects that don't change. When creating a new array or object, copy all the values that don't change, and don't deep copy those. Using rest spread is a handy way to do these things.

Comment: Thanks @DDS. I got this idea just a week or two back. I was recommending this to a few people at work, of late. And now in SO. Realise that it is pretty dumb! :) No wonder, I hit so many breakpoints while debugging.

Answer (score 1):

When using Redux you want to treat the state as immutable. The reducer should return a new state object, not modify the existing one. If you run INITIAL_STATE['postLists'] = somethingNew; you are modifying the object referenced by INITIAL_STATE.

Instead of using the spread operator in this case is to use Object.assign, which will create a new object based on an existing object and overload some properties.

That being said, you should not really use INITIAL_STATE at all except as the default value of state in the reducer definition.